# Why chdir does not support in java?

Tags: java

I would like to know the actual reason behind why Java does not provide chdir call implementation however it provides native interfaces for the same.

Comment: It is unusable in any multi-threaded application. You really don't want to do this.

Comment: Hi Ejp, Thanks but I need to know the reason. I mean if I do chdir from the running program in java what problems it would arise  ? And why native interfaces are being provided ?  Is there any specific reason for this case ?

Comment: If you use a native interface *and* you use Java's security model for file accesses, then you can break the security model - if you chdir while another thread (or close to the time another thread - given memory consistency issues with multiple thread) does the access control check, you may be able to access a file that you should be able to given the active security policy.

Comment: Thanks a lot.   That means it contrary to the safety principle provided by the Java. Got it!

Comment: If one thread calls it with one directory and another thread calls it with another directory, the first thread is now not in the directory it thinks it's in, without notice.

Answer (score 2):

The full evaluation can be found in Sun/Oracle's bug database with issue number 
[JDK-4045688 : Add chdir or equivalent notion of changing working directory](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4045688)

It was decided to close the ticket because there are major issues with any solution, and none of the customers that reported the bug really needed it - all of them were able to use a workaround.

One excerpt from the bug database that highlights the issues with adding such a call:

> EVALUATION
>
> This feature can be interpreted in two ways: chdir could change the
>   current working directory of the process containing the JVM, causing
>   all threads to change simultaneously, or to provide a more "virtual"
>   per-thread concept of current directory, which could conceptually be a
>   ThreadLocal.  This would be merely a convenience for building up
>   complete path names to pass to the underlying operating system API.
>
> This is how the current directory works in Emacs - it's just a
>   variable, but a magic one that can have buffer-local values.  Emacs
>   buffers are kinda sorta like Java threads in this sense. Such an
>   implementation would offer convenience and safety. Having each thread
>   with a ThreadLocal current directory gives a programmer experience
>   familiar to old Unix greybeards, except that Threads replace
>   Processes.

Many workarounds are also described there, such as executing a subprocess with a new current directory, or always qualifying your file accesses with the parent directory from where you want your relative part to start.

Comment: Thanks Erwin. Then its because of its I/O architecture mechanism causing problems in multi threaded application.